# NSButton attributedTitle changes color on button down

Tags: macos, cocoa, checkbox, macos-mojave, nscolor

I created a Cocoa app with a button on it, having the "Check" style and "Switch" type. It is set to a custom class `MyButton`:

```
@interface MyButton : NSButton
- (void)awakeFromNib;
@end
```

This custom class sets `attributedTitle`:

```
@implementation MyButton
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];       
    [self setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hallo" attributes:@{
    }]];
}
@end
```

When the button is checked, the font color changes on mouse-down.

I read that [`NSAttributedString`'s default color is black](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsforegroundcolorattributename?language=objc), but when I set it to black explicitly, it stays black on mouse-down. If I explicitly ask for `[NSColor controlTextColor]`, the color switches on mouse-down. Is this behaviour documented somewhere? Is it intended or a bug?

Comment: Did you try setting the `attributedAlternateTitle`?

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla I did (with the same parameter), but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you may want to subclass NSButtonCell and override some methods.

One possible avenue is overriding NSCell's method

```
- (NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
```

This is one of many frustrating button drawing problems.  After trying to bend NSButtonCell drawing to my needs, I ended up drawing everything myself.
I started with the ancient but awesome BGHUDAppKit, and heavily modded it to fit my needs.  BGHUDAppKit is monstrous, but at least now I can easily debug or workaround most drawing bugs.  I feel for all the people that will encounter bugs similar to this as they try to support Mojave dark mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I stepped back from using `NSAttributedString` entirely and now go with just `setFont`, which seems to work fine so far.